# Integral of derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $f$ be continous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable a.e. on $(a,b)$. Suppose there is a non-negative 
   function $g$ integrable on $[a,b]$ and $|\displaystyle \frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}|\leq g$ a.e on $[a,b]$ for all $n$.

How can I show that: $\quad\displaystyle\int_a^bf'=f(b)-f(a). $

Comment: @Bunny: Maybe you could use one of the convergence theorems (for integrals).  Can you think of one that might help?

Answer (score 2):

Using Dominated Convergence, and writing $F$ for an antiderivative of $f$,
$$
\int_{[a,b]}f'=\int_{[a,b]}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[a,b]}\frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}\\ =\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_{[a,b]}{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_{a+1/n}^{b+1/n}{f(x)-n\int_a^bf(x)}
\\ =\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_{b}^{b+1/n}{f(x)-n\int_a^{a+1/n}f(x)}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F(b+1/n)-F(b)}{1/n}-\frac{F(a+1/n)-F(a)}{1/n}\\
=F'(b)-F'(a)=f(b)-f(a)
$$

Comment: Martin: How do you know that $f(x)$ is integrable on $[a+1/n, b+1/n]$?

Comment: Note that by hypothesis, $f(x+1/n)-f(x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ (if you want, this is a defect of the question, as it does not mention that $f$ actually needs to be defined outside $[a,b]$). As $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ it is integrable there; so $f(x+1/n)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. And $$\int_a^b|f(x+1/n)|dx=\int_{a+1/n}^{b+1/n}|f(x)|dx,$$ so $f$ is integrable on $[a+1/n,b+1/n]$.